# JasperReport Export HTML Height

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm generating Jaspert report as HTML then embed it into my JSP page, Jasper report creates an iFrame for it, but the height of the iframe is fixed to 650, is there a way to change this?

I want the page to display the full report, right now it is cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using CSS:

```
height: <what you want here>;
```

Remember that the `< >` is just to ilustrate, don't put they, please.